Can I get the carrier country on iOs if a sim is still not activated
Is there any way to get the country of a sim that is not activated (like a new not activated ultra mobile sim, so it doesnt have any number yet)?

You can no longer get the sim country code regardless of the sim state.

how does tiktok get the country via sim then?

Why do think TikTok can do this?

if you insert chinese number sim card, tiktok won't work, I've seen people saying tiktok determines your region by sim card and not location/ip

They may be using a service with a carrier side component such as https://idlayr.com/
